# How to find the order of a pole

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

How can I find the order of the pole $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $f(z)=\frac{1}{(2\log(z))(1-\sin(z))}$? I know the answer should be 2, but I can't solve it, mostly due to poor understanding of the pole order theory. As far as I've understood, the order should be equal to the index of the first non-zero member of the expansion in a series. However, I don't know how to expand this function in the singularity for a Taylor series, and a geometrical series doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Remember that another definition of a pole of order k is $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}z^k f(z)\neq 0, \pm \infty$

Comment: you can find the zeros of the function $\log z (1-\sin z)$, after this, you can to find the order of this zeros, (you can to do this with help of the derivates and evaluate in this zeros to find one number different of zero), finally if you zero has order $n$ then is a pole if order $n$. Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $2\log(z)$ does not vanish at $z=\frac\pi2$, so we can ignore it; it does not contribute to the pole. So consider simply $\dfrac1{1-\sin(z)}$. We want to write things in terms of $w = z-\frac\pi2$, so let $\sin(z)=\sin(w+\frac\pi2) = \cos(w)$, where at the end I have used a simple trig formula. Then we can expand $\cos(w) = 1-\frac{w^2}2+\frac{w^4}{24}-...$, so $\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(w)} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{w^2}2-\frac{w^4}{24}+...} = \dfrac1{w^2(\frac12-\frac{w^2}{24}+...)}$. Thus, we can see that the order of the pole is 2.

Answer (score 1):

you have the function $h(z)=\log(z)(1-\sin z)$ then

$h(\pi/2)=0$,

$h'(z)= \frac{1-\sin z}{z}- \log z \cos z$ then $h'(\pi/2)=0$

$h''(z)= \frac{-z\cos z-(1-\sin z)}{z^2}-\frac{\cos z}{z}+\log z\sin z$ then $h''(\pi/2)\ne 0$ hence $\pi/2$ is a zero of order two for $h$, therefore is a pole for $\frac{1}{h(z)}$ of order two.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(z)=\frac{ 1/\log z^2}{(1-\sin z)}=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$

Observe that $g(z)$ is analytic and non- zero at $z=\pi/2$ hence the order of zero of $h(z)$ there determines the order of pole for rational function $f(z)$.

$h(\pi/2)=h'(\pi/2)=0$ and $h''(\pi/2)\ne 0$ suggests $h(z)$ has zero of order $2$ at $z=\pi/2$ so $f(z)$ has pole of order $2$ there.